# Grunt/Clean task: "Not actually cleaning" message

Tags: gruntjs

With the following clean configuration, this simple grunt clean task is not working.  It did not remove the specified folder/directory called target.

```
clean: {
        options: {
            "no-write": true
        },
        buildTargetDir: {
            'src': ['target']
        }
    }
```

With "no-write" option, I got the following output:

```
Running "clean:buildTargetDir" (clean) task
Not actually cleaning target...OK

Done, without errors.
```

I checked the following:

1) Permissions on the folder. Did not work even after running chmod 777 on it.

2) Emptied the folder. No luck.

When do we get this error message: Not actually cleaning ...OK

It is strange to see that the final output says "Done, without errors" but the tasks output says "Not actually cleaning".

The plugin used here is: grunt-contrib-clean

Comment: Vijey, might be you have something like this in your Gruntfile (or you had, given this question was made a year ago): `grunt.task.registerTask('clean', ['loremipsum']);`. If so, removing it will make clean task work ok.

Comment: Thanks Fernando.  Will check that.

Answer (score 1):

`Not actually cleaning target...OK` is not an error message.  It's a direct result from you setting `"no write"` to `true`.

Directly from the [grunt-contrib-clean docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean#no-write):

> **no-write**
>
> Type: `Boolean` Default: `false`
>
> Will log messages of what would happen if the task was ran but doesn't
>   actually delete the files.

Sooooooo....this is not an error.  The plugin is doing exactly what you asked it to do.

Comment: Yes. I agree that it is not an error message.  But the point is why it is not deleting the directory and giving me this message. Setting "no-write" to true just enables logging and it will not affect the clean process. What I am looking for is: why the directory was not removed and why I am getting this message and what could be wrong with the setup?

Comment: And the point is that `no-write` is an option that explicitly tells the plugin NOT to delete the files or directory.  If you want the plugin to delete things, `no-write` needs to be false or you can remove the line entirely as it defaults to false.

Comment: Yes.  I tried that as well.  I just removed the whole options (which has this no-write settings) and ran the task.  No luck.  The directory was not removed.

Comment: ...and did the message 'Not actually cleaning target' stop appearing?

Comment: Yes. It did.  I gave a success message like "Cleaning target...OK" but did not remove the directory.  That is why it is puzzling to me.

Comment: OK.  So your original question is answered.  You are now investigating a different problem than this question describes.  You should ask a new question that includes your current gruntfile, the output when you run the task, and your directory structure.